# How to make entry of user when password is wrong

Tags: authentication, yii

In yii i am creating login module. I want to give access to users only if username and passwords are correct and need to store this user's id into 'Success' table. But when only username is correct and password is wrong,i want to store that user's id into 'attempt' table in order to give only 3 chance to him for entering correct password. But when i am implementing this,when password is wrong entry doesnt get enterd into attempt table. i had created ActionLogin() method as-

```
public function actionLogin()
{
    $model=new LoginForm;
    $command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand();

    // if it is ajax validation request
    if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='login-form')
    {
        echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
        Yii::app()->end();
    }

    // collect user input data
    if(isset($_POST['LoginForm']))
    {
         $model->attributes=$_POST['LoginForm'];
         // validate user input and redirect to the previous page if valid
         if ($model->validate()) 
         {
            if($model->login()) {
                      $command->insert('attempt', array(
                      'id'=>Yii::app()->user->getId(),
                       ));
                      $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
             }  
            if(!$model->login())
            {            
            $command->insert('attempt', array(
            'id'=>Yii::app()->user->getId(),
                   ));
             } 
            }
     }

    // display the login form
    $this->render('login',array('model'=>$model));
}
```

What changes i need to do in order to make entry of user's id into attempt table when password is wrong. Please help me.

Comment: if the user failed to log in (wrong password) wouldn't `Yii::app()->user->getId()` be blank/null?

Comment: Actually i want to keep records of visiting users also. So need to insert user's id into Attempt table when username is correct and password is wrong.

Comment: Visitors don't have userIds...

Comment: @ThomasVdBerge my point exactly ;)

Comment: So is it not possible to store record of number of attempts made by user to make login?

Comment: yes, you could store the username they submit in the form, i.e. `$_POST['username']`, or whatever you call it in your script?

Comment: Or you can store a user his IP and only allow a certain amount of invalid logins/IP.

I do believe the best way to achieve what you are doing would be to store it as a session.

Comment: @ThomasVdBerge is right, storing by IP would probably be a better approach, that'd cover people trying to hack multiple usernames as well.

Comment: The session is not correct because if the user close the browser and goes back then he has more attempts. The solution is to store only the ip address and the attempts and a time threshold to allow or not additional attempts.

Comment: @NikosTsirakis sir can you please guide me in what way i can do this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments:

A user that is visiting a Yii based website doesn't have a user id assigned, only logged in users have a userId assigned (which makes sense...).

The best approach would be to do IP based checks on the login attempts. You can retrieve a user his IP by the following piece of code:

```
Yii::app()->request->userHostAddress
```

Also credits for this answer to @Stu and @Nikos-Tsirakis